# Do position and momentum measurements determine a wave function?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-analysis, inverse-problems

Suppose we have a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and we know the functions $x\mapsto|f(x)|$ and $p\mapsto|\hat f(p)|$, where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.
Can we reconstruct the function $f$ itself, up to a phase factor?
If $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ with $|\lambda|=1$, then $f$ and $\lambda f$ give exactly the same data, but I see no other obstructions.
(**Update:** The answer is no. See [this article](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FANZ%2FANZ20_02%2FS0334270000001569a.pdf). A related question is given in the next paragraph.)

Alternatively, one could consider the same problem for $f\in L^2(\mathbb T^n)$ on the torus $\mathbb T^n=\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$:
Do the functions $\mathbb T^n\ni x\mapsto |f(x)|$ and $\mathbb Z^n\ni p\mapsto|\hat f(p)|$ determine $f$ uniquely?
(**Note:** Since Qiaochu Yuan gave an answer to the Euclidean case, this is the only remaining question. I originally chose to leave this part out, but I suppose it's better to edit the question now than to ask a new one.)

If $f$ is a quantum mechanical wave function, position measurements give the function $x\mapsto|f(x)|^2$ and momentum measurements the function $p\mapsto|\hat f(p)|^2$.
Assuming we can prepare a particle to the same state (same wave function) as many times as we wish, we can in principle carry out these measurements.
From a physical point of view, the question is whether these measurements determine the wave function up to the nonphysical phase factor.
Position and momentum are in a sense a good pair of observables, so I would expect the answer to be affirmative on physical grounds.

One could write $f(x)=\alpha(x)r(x)$ where $|\alpha(x)|\equiv1$ and $r(x)\in\mathbb R$ and similarly $\hat f(p)=\beta(p)s(p)$, and then try to use identities for Fourier transforms of products and find one of the unknown functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of the known functions $r$ and $s$.
(Actually, we can only possibly find $\alpha$ in the support of $r$, but that's enough.)
I don't see an obvious way to solve the resulting equations, even with formal calculations.

If the problem becomes easier, an answer for a Schwartz function $f$ in dimension $n=1$ is ok.
I would like to see a method for reconstructing $f$ from the given data, but a proof that the data does determine $f$ uniquely would also be great.

Comment: The answer appears to be no. Google led me to http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FANZ%2FANZ20_02%2FS0334270000001569a.pdf&code=02e1428e1012c47881bc6fe8a66d382c.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, great, thanks! I had originally left out another case I was interested in (on the torus), but I included it now since that article settles the original question.

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81303/2451